# ImageView Scaling for No Apparent Reason

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I'm using Android Studio, and have created an ImageView in activity_mail.xml. The layout width and height are set to "match_parent". The scaleType is set to "center" and the source image is 70x70 pixels. When I run the app in the emulator the Image appears on the screen larger than 70x70 pixels. I mean it takes up more than 70x70 pixels on the screen of the phone. I don't know why it's doing this. The app is exclusively in Landscape mode, that might be relevant. Forgive me if I have included extraneous details, I genuinely don't know what information would be relevant to include. I intend to make it so that the image takes up 70x70 pixels on the screen of the phone. What is causing the unintended result, and how could I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) It'll be easier for people to help you, if you provide a minimal code example to reproduce the issue, along with the Android version and the phone type you use. This has also the nice side effect that by creating a minimal version of your problem you limit the possibile origins of the error and might even solve it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `ScaleType`, maybe `fit_center` instead of just `center` + `android:adjustViewBounds="true”` will fit your purposes... another way is to create `ImageView` with `wrap_content` sizes placed in some container (e.g. `RelativeLayout`) with `match_parent` sizes

also check this [visual guide](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide) for `ScaleType`

note that 70px image will be big on devices with HD resolution and significantly smaller on those with e.g. full HD. you should have few versions of your image in proper density buckets (`mdpi`, `hdpi` etc.) or just download proper size if your image comes frome some API, so then you can say that you have image with `70dp` dimension, not `70px`